# First Order Logic Question: How to interpret ∀x~∃y when L(x,y) means ___x loves ___y?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am given a sentence and my professor wishes for me to convert it to FOL. The problem is that I do not know what the form of this quantifier order would look like. For instance, if L(x,y) means ___x loves ___y.This is not the real question, as I want to learn it on my own. But, How would I interpret it through the aforementioned quantifier sequence. My initial thought is that it would mean something like, 'Everyone does not love somebody." Really I'm completely lost. Thanks.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907045/negating-a-symbolic-expression-logic/2907052#2907052) help? Basically, $\forall$ is equivalent to $\lnot \exists \lnot$ and $\exists$ is equivalent to $\lnot \forall \lnot$ (these quantifiers are dual). By double negation elimination this means $\lnot \exists$ is equivalent to $\forall \lnot$. Unfortunately, I can't find a question that *just* covers the duality of $\forall$ and $\exists$ without any extra detail. The simplest way to state the meaning of that wff is *no one loves anyone*.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly literal translation of

> ∀x~∃yL(x,y)

would be

> For every x, there is no y, such that x loves y.

And a less literal version:

> Everthing loves nothing.

If we assume the domain of objects are persons instead of ojects in general, this means:

> Everyone loves no-one.

The latter is equivalent to

> Nobody loves anyone.

Which would be formalized as

> ~∃x∃yL(x,y)

This is logically equivalent to the first expression above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just building off what you said, so for a quantifier pairing of ~∀x∃yL(x,y), it would be similar to saying: 'For no x, there is some y, such that x loves y? And that would be equivalent too, No one loves someone?

Comment: @mivology1 No, those sentences would mean ~∃x∃yL(x,y). ~∀x∃yL(x,y), on the other hand, means "Not for every x there is a y such that x loves y". Or "Not everything loves something". Or again for people, "Not everyone loves someone". In short, "~∃" means "no" or "nothing" or "not something", while "~∀" means "not every", "not all", "not everything".